# If value = 0000 Insert and set value with max()+1

Tags: mysql, select

I need to get the maximum value +1 for a field, if that filed as the 0000 value.

```
IF
  (acc_id = 0000)
FROM
  crm_accounts;
INSERT
INTO
  crm_accounts(acc_id)
SELECT MAX
  (acc_id) + 1
FROM
  crm_accounts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to do an `UPDATE` statement...

This should get it done for you:

```
SELECT @id := MAX(acc_id) FROM crm_accounts;
UPDATE crm_accounts
SET acc_id = @id := @id + 1
WHERE acc_id = 0000;
```

Comment: Thank's for your effort. I thinks this is the way to solve the problem, but i get this error:

Table 'crm_accounts' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: @jmsf Applied a change to my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Pachonk. Thanks for your quick response. The change works fine, but now i have a new problem.. all the '0000' rows are updated to the same value.

Comment: Hmm. I thought that MAY be an issue. Going out to zoo and when I get back I should be able to fix her up.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience and enjoy the zoo :D :D

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks for everything Pachonk.

Comment: Sorry again Pachonk, but is there any way to put this on a mysql trigger? I get the following error message "Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.."

Comment: You should just make the column auto incrementing and that should solve your issue.